# How to automate Python Dash app data pull?

Tags: python, ethereum, plotly-dash

I am building a Dash app (screenshots of UI are also available at the github link) that is used to identify large buy / sell-walls on the cryptocurrency exchange GDAX thanks to the python API they have set up.

My 2 big questions are as follows (calling all Python / Dash coders for their advice):

1 - How do I go about automating the data pull so that it doens't require manual refresh. I essentially just need some code that automates the data pull every second (or, if that's too hard, does it whenever there is a manual refresh via the browser).

2 - How do I host this publicly so that everyone else can use it? (I don't have experience publishing Dash apps, so any advice would be great.)

https://github.com/pmaji/eth_python_tracker/blob/master/app.py

Answer (score 2):

1. Dash documentation has a great page for setting up a live updating dashboard
   https://plot.ly/dash/live-updates

I wrote up a toy example for a talk I gave a few months back. Code is [available on Github](https://github.com/alysivji/talks/blob/master/data-science-workflows-using-docker-containers/workflow3-data-driven-app/plot_timeseries.py)

Trick is to add an `Interval` component:

`dcc.Interval(
    id='interval-component',
    interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
    n_interval=0)`

2. pythonanywhere.com makes it really easy to host webapps. Dash apps are Flask apps so you can follow [instructions on their website](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/#ive-got-an-existing-web-app-that-im-trying-to-deploy)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am still having trouble hosting this on pythonanywhere, so I may look for other alternatives. I set up a virtual environment but it was constantly throwing errors when I tried to simply import dash in my code.

Comment: Contact PythonAnywhere support with the error. We can probably help.

Comment: I think the dcc.Interval() stuff only refreshes the dashboard, not the data pull, right? Thanks